# Call Back API VK и WindowsForm С#

Tags: c#, winforms, vkontakte-api, callback

Задалась целью написать простенького бота для вк на C#. Хочу, чтобы бот был в сообщениях группы. И через них же реагировал на команды и отвечал пользователям. Для этого мне необходимо подключить callback api vk, чтобы бот реагировал на отправленные ему сообщения и на команды.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу подключить callbak api от вк в свою программу на Windows Form? VkNet смотрела, там эти функции не реализованы.

И еще мне не ясен механизм доставки запросов от вк, например, я запущу программу на своем компьютере, как информация будет попадать ко мне в программу, нужно указать, чтобы она какой то конкретный порт прослушивала?

И последний вопрос, как я могу напрямую работать с методомами vkontakte api через свою программу, верно ли я поняла, что просто нужно отправлять команду на api.vk.com/methods/?

Спасибо!

Comment: Суть Callback в том, что тут не вы отправляете запрос на сайт, а сайт отправляет запрос вам и обычно это происходит путем отправки POST запроса на определенный HTTP адрес (сайт). В WinForms сами понимаете, что такое делать как то не очень, но не кто не мешает вам попробовать)

Comment: Спасибо! Я так понимаю, мне тогда проще и лучше для моих целей вообще PHP взять?

Comment: CallBack подразумевает сервис/сервер на стороне клиента. В вашем случае http, можно использовать Http Listener Class https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Я понимаю, что не я к нему буду запросы посылать, а что он мне будет json присылать, о событии, документацию я читала, просто не поняла, как это конкретно можно реализовать.

Comment: @АлинаФельдштейн Ну это уже как вам будет удобней. Если вам нужно приложение WinForms, то я бы сделал сайт, к которому подключался клиент (WinForms) через WCF или его аналоги, либо мониторил определенный API сайта. А сам сайт, обрабатывал бы запросы от VK и отсылал нужным клиентам. Но HTTP адрес тут как не крути нужен...

Comment: Это если конечно клиентов больше одного. Если один, то либо на чистом Web делать, либо как я написал выше, реализуйте http в приложение WinForms (но тут лично я не уверен в надежности такого соединения...)

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. Я не слишком пока заинтересована в надежности. Просто хотела бы создать что то осязаемое, чтобы так сказать "пощупать" можно было.